# Cosa significa "giorno di banco"?

Tags: meaning

Nel romanzo *Artemisia*, di Anna Banti, ho letto:

> «Gervasio, creatura, avvisa Antonio che c'è la sua Artemisia. T'ha aspettato tutti i giorni: un boccone e un sospiro. Ma sai com'è attento, e oggi è giorno di banco a Piazza Navona.»

La mia domanda è sul significato dell'espressione "giorno di banco" in questo brano. Vuol dire giorno di mercato?

Comment: A parte che è *giorno di mercato* come dice @Josh61, nel contesto significa che Antonio era effettivamente impegnato al mercato quel giorno.

Answer (score 1):

Si rifericse a quelle che comunemente sono chiamate ***[bancarelle](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/bancarella/)***:

> - bancarèlla (non com. bancherèlla) s. f. [der. di banca, forma ant. per panca o banco]. – Banco o carretto su cui espongono la loro merce i venditori ambulanti. (Teccani.it)

Da  ([mercatidiroma.com](http://mercatidiroma.com/pulci/natalizio-navona)):

> - Come Luca, ***un banco di statuine per il presepe*** che racconta: “Io sono  figlio di un'artigiana di piazza Navona...."

- Da cui, giorno di banco significa giorno di mercato.